# Using duplicate headers in Powershell .csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a .csv file and I want to import it into powershell then iterate through the file changing certain values. I then want the output to append to the original .csv file, so that the values have been updated.

My issue is that the .csv file has headers which aren't unique, and can't be changed as then it won't work in another program. Originally I defined my own headers in the powershell to get around this but then the output file has these new headers when it needs to have the old ones.

I have also tried `ConvertFrom-Csv` which means I can no longer access the columns I need to, so lots of runtime errors.

What would be ideal is to be able to use the defined column headers and then convert back to the original column headers. My current code is below:

```
$csvfile = Import-Csv C:\test.csv| Where-Object {$_.'3' -eq $classID} | ConvertFrom-Csv
foreach($record in $csvfile){
*do something*}
$csvfile | Export-Csv -path C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I've searched the web now for some hours and tried everything I've come across, to no avail.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An object can't have duplicate properties (what would that mean?). Do you know how many columns the CSV file contains?

Comment: The CSV file contains 78 columns. The headers are the type of data they contain, either long or byte. However powershell doesn't allow me to keep these as the headers as they aren't unique

Comment: 1. open file with custom headers
2. export file with custom headers
3. remove first line of file
4. profit ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat hackish implementation but should work.

1. Remove all the headers as a single line and save it somewhere
2. Parse the new result-set (with the headers removed)
3. Add the line at the top when you are finished

A CSV is a comma delimited file, you don't have to treat it like structured data. Feel free to splice and dice as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this isn't really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know beforehand how many columns are in the input CSV file, you can import without the header and process internally. Example:

```
$columns = 78

Import-Csv "inputfile.csv" -Header (0..$($columns - 1)) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
  $row = $_
  $outputObject = New-Object PSObject
  0..$($columns- 1) | ForEach-Object {
    $outputObject | Add-Member NoteProperty "Col$_" $row.$_
  }
  $outputObject
} | Export-Csv "outputfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This example generates new PSObjects and then outputs a new CSV file with generic column names (Col0, Col1, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this out when I have a chance and post back.